Are there any well-known political considerations for having a friend on the job market come for a visit and talk?
I'm in my second year as an assistant professor in a STEM subject in the US. A colleague and friend in the same subject (but a different specialization) has some travel money at their disposal and has expressed an interest in visiting and giving a talk this (fall) semester. In fact, we worked with the same postdoc mentor in my previous job. I expect they'll give a good talk and would be happy to arrange this in general.
In the upcoming job cycle, the decisions for which will mostly execute in the spring, our department has a strong possibility of hiring in an area where I think my friend is a good fit. I don't expect to be on the committee for that, but even if I were I'd bring up the relationship in case that was perceived as a conflict of interest. We'd get many qualified candidates in the usual way, of course, and if my friend applied they'd still have the same commensurately stochastic experience as anyone else.
Perhaps I am overly cautious, but I am also a bit concerned that I may be missing some piece of academic cultural information about having them visit. I am both concerned about the etiquette as it reflects on me, and also with not accidentally lowering my friend's chances over some procedural faux pas.
Is this simply not an actual problem, or is there any well-known protocol for approaching the situation?

The specifics of this question are somewhat niche, but I'm reasonably hopeful that they generalize in a useful way. It sits at that irritating place with our "individual factors" guidelines where I can't quite tell whether there's a good answer or "it depends" is all that's available.

Does your friend tell you s/he wants to apply for your university?

@MahaliSindy yes.

What's the problem? This is  "networking", and it's common in both industry and academia.

There is no conflict of interest between promoting someone as a speaker and as a potential hire on the shared basis that you work well with them and they're good at their job.  You should in fact be referring high-quality candidates to open roles, assuming you are happy with your employer, and all the better if they can provide other benefits like this talk.

@Barmar I think I described the potential problem pretty accurately. This may feel obvious to you for whatever reason, but it were to me I wouldn't have asked. ;)

I admit I've never been in academia, I just read this site out of curiosity. But it often seems like posters are making mountains out of molehills, they think they'll be demonized for every little transgression.

@Barmar I know what you mean about some level of catastrophizing, but despite my username I've been around here for a long while (deleted an account with the last strike). There's a confluence of factors in this situation that made me a little cautious-- the answers have confirmed my gut feeling which is that this isn't an especially big deal.

From the title, I was expecting the question to be "is it okay to invite my friend who is on the job market to give a talk, when I know there is no chance they will be hired?" That can be a bit of an awkward situation, and I do think that people should disclose it to the invitee -- everyone has limited time and money for travel, and it is unfair to invite someone to what looks like an informal job talk when it isn't one. The OP's actual situation, though, is completely normal and I see nothing that they should worry about.

I'm pretty sure you're overthinking this. It is standard and appropriate for early-career researchers to go around giving as many talks as possible, in as many places as possible, and especially in places where they are (or will be soon) applying for jobs. And it is standard, and to the best of my knowledge considered appropriate, for acquaintances of those early-career researchers in various departments who know about their situations and have good opinions about them to help get them invited to give talks at their departments. Here's a good way to think about this issue: as a faculty member you have just as much right as any other faculty member in your department to recommend anyone you want to give talks or (if you are given authority over the relevant seminar) to invite them to give talks yourself.
I have myself seen such situations many times and been a party to them myself. I am not aware that anyone ever saw this as a problem. Job search or no, people invite their friends to give talks all the time, and this generally helps further the department's research mission and works to everyone's benefit.
Moreover, about the job search: depending on how hiring works in your department, you may even be given a voice in who gets hired, and then too it would be entirely appropriate for you to voice the opinion that your friend should be hired for the position. The "conflict of interest" of your sharing a postdoc mentor with this person and being on friendly terms with them is so common and standard that no one will perceive it as an actual conflict. It might be wise to mention that connection during any discussions about the seminar invitation or the job search, but I would advise you not to mention it in a way that suggests that you think it may bias or compromise your good (and I assume honest) opinion of your friend's scientific work. The reason for this is that if you give out the impression that you don't trust the integrity of your own opinion, other people in the department who support other candidates may well take advantage of your hesitancy and use that to tilt the job search in favor of their own preferred candidates (who may well be their "friends" in the same sense that you regard your supported candidate as a friend, and make them just as "conflicted" in the hypothetical sense as you're describing). So in an attempt to be completely impartial and avoid unfairly biasing the job search in favor of your friend, you might end up accidentally injecting yet another, unintended, source of unfairness and bias into the process - a kind of unfairness that works against your friend instead of in their favor. So my recommendation is simply to state your honest opinion about your friend, let others state theirs, and let the chips fall where they may without worrying about these microscopic conflicts of interest, which in academia are pretty much ubiquitous and impossible to avoid.
To be clear, it is always possible for some people to raise some hypothetical ethical objections to inviting someone you consider a friend to give a talk when this person is or soon will be a job candidate. These sorts of concerns may have some validity in the abstract. And while I don't think they make much sense in the real-world context we are discussing, there's no guarantee that you won't end up stepping on someone's weird sensibilities. It's also possible that in your particular institution or your particular discipline there are some unusual norms that make this sort of thing a faux pas. You may want to consult a knowledgeable person in your department to really make sure that your inviting your friend won't bother anyone. But as far as my general experience in US STEM (mostly math) academia goes, this is a non-issue.

Since you won't be the one inviting them (the department will) there is no issue in you recommending them for a visit, provided that you reveal that you are their friend and, so, have a small conflict of interest.
You can say why you think they are a good person to come talk and why they might be a good fit on the faculty, but let others make decisions and stay out of the hiring process. The discussion is probably with the department head or the PI of some working group with the authority to make an invitation.
And, if you wind up on the hiring committee you should (must) recuse from the process in their case. A faculty member who is not in the hiring process can advocate for individuals whom they know. Honesty is required, of course.

Norms must vary substantially between fields. In my field, it is not unusual for individuals to chair committees that end up hiring their former trainees.

@Ian, more likely senior faculty, though, I'd guess. Not second year assistant professors. And, in some fields, professors are directly responsible for hiring decisions, having the grant funding to enable it.

I will answer job related question.
Best reference letter is from someone within the target company/university. The reason behind this is that the referrer, at least to a degree, cares about the hiring company/institution. You will have no idea whether the referrer will care enough to even screen the candidate. Additionally, hiring department will have the chance to question referrer much easier for particular details and the referrer has a particularly good reason to answer them honestly as it might hurt their reputation with the company.
Therefore, it is not only ethical to refer your friend, any and all forms are fine, including calling them in to demonstrate their skills, it is beneficial to your department too.
Just a small warning though, do not recommend someone to the company you are working for unless you know them well-enough.


You are not in the position of decision making so your recommendation, if true and honest, is not in any conflict. If you approach your department head saying: "Bob, a friend of mine, is interested in giving a talk about [something] and I think it is wotrh it." is completely fine.

The hiring process of general announcement - candidates interview - candidates evaluation - contract negotiation - contract is not the only way. It can happen that you want This One Person to work for you.
If your friend impresses your department so much the head can approach your HR: "We want to hire Bob, make it so."


You are overthinking this. If you (plural) are honest and true there is no problem. Problem starts when you are not honest (hiding the relationship with Bob) and/or when you are not true (you inflate his expertise so he gets the position).
Research is not a pool, it's rather a puddle so researchers know each other. The more specialized the field is the smaller the puddle is so the conflicts of interest are almost inevitable.

"so the conflicts of interest are almost inevitable" yes - but also: everyone else knows who gets along with whom, who don't get along with each other.
